# Push Notification using GCM without own Server

Tags: android, notifications, push

I want to create push notifications for android using GCM but without setting up my own server. Are there any third party servers who provides this facility ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Tarun, is it free ?

Comment: I used Pushwoosh, google is your friend anyway...

Comment: It is free till 1Million pushes/month

Comment: @Tarun - Thanks will try it out its SDK.

Comment: @lelloman - Looks like Pushwoosh is promising too and its free till 1 million users. Once you sign up do they give you web portal page from where you can push messages ?

Comment: yes you can send notifications for free from their site, they also offer web API but not for free :)

Comment: cool...Tarun is it same in Urban Airship ? Once i sign in do i get a portal to send messages ? (Basic Features) are okay for me if it is free

Comment: Yes. they have a nice portal and its easy to implement as well..

Comment: @Tarun - Thanks Tarun, will try it out soon and update reviews

Answer (score 1):

How about Amazon Simple Notification Service?
http://aws.amazon.com/en/sns/